# Отобрать строку между заданными символами

Tags: php

Есть така строка

> 2018-10-18 04:13:10

Из нее средствами php нужно получить

> 18

и

> 04:13:10

а из

> 04:13:10

получить

> 4:13:10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вспомнил что можно делать вот так

```
$testimonialDay = date('d',strtotime($testimonialDate));
$testimonialMonth = date('m',strtotime($testimonialDate));
$testimonialYear = date('Y',strtotime($testimonialDate));
$testimonialTime = date('H:i',strtotime($testimonialDate));

<p class="date"><?php echo $testimonialDay ." ". $testimonialMonth ." ". $testimonialYear ." в ". $testimonialTime; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще вариант, дальше вариантов вывода миллион
 http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

```
$date = date_create('2018-10-18 04:13:10');
echo date_format($date, 'y');
echo '<br>';
echo date_format($date, 'g:m:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '2018-10-18 04:13:10';

preg_match_all('~(?<int>(?<=-)\d+(?=\h))|(?<time>(?<=\h\d)\d(?::\d{2}){2})~', $str, $arr);
$arr = array_map('array_filter', $arr);

var_dump( $arr['int'], $arr['time'] );
```

Результат:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string '18'
array (size=1)
  1 => string '4:13:10'
```